# Difference between @bind and @bind-value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

What is the difference of using `@bind` and `@bind-value`?

I made this simple example, and testing it in the browser, I didn't see any difference.

```
<p>@@bind @increment1</p>

<input 
    type="text"
    @bind="@increment1"
/>

<p>@@bind-value @increment2</p>
<input 
    type="text"
    @bind-value="@increment2"
/>

@code {
    string increment1;
    string increment2;
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Short Version

`@bind` is an override of `@bind-value` with the event set to "onchange".

These two commands are equivalent:

```
 ... @bind-value="userName" @bind-value:event="onchange" ...
 ... @bind="userName" ...
```

### Long Version

The `@bind` attribute accomplishes two separate (but related) tasks:

1. Binds an expression to the value of the `<Input...` component
2. Binds a delegate that will trigger the component's `ValueChanged` property

*Both* the expression and the delegate are **required**. An implementation of `@bind-Value` looks like this:

```
 ... @bind-value="userName" @bind-value:event="onchange" ...
```

We are setting *both* the expression (`="userName"`) and the delegate (`="onchange"`).

The "easier" `@bind=` is just an **override** with the delegate preset to "onchange". So these two commands are functionally the same:

```
 ... @bind-value="userName" @bind-value:event="onchange" ...
 ... @bind="userName" ...
```

A greatly simplified analogy using overriding methods:

```
public void bind-value(string value, string event)
{..}

public void bind(string value)
{
  bind-value(value, "onchange");
}
```

A couple of common use-cases for using the full `@bind-value` version are

1. updating the UI *as* the user types
2. validating an email address *as* the user types

Remember, the `onchange` event will only trigger `PropertyChanged` when the component *loses focus*. Instead, we want `PropertyChanged` to be triggered by the `oninput` event:

```
... @bind-value="H1Content" @bind-value:event="oninput" ...
... @bind-value="email" @bind-value:event="oninput" ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to also specify a callback that get's called? I know we can set just value"MyValue" @onchange="myCallback" but it's inconsistent on the update. Calling it on the Set of MyValue (which is a Component Parameter in this case) is not recommended i think.

Comment: `@bind-value="userName"` will also default to `onchange`. There is no difference between the 2.

Answer (score 17):

**EDITED** because [@dragon-warrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3725955/dragon-warrior) and [@somedotnetguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17562157/somedotnetguy) coments.

#### ASP.NET >= Core 3.1

`@bind-value:event` is not more required for events. Just use `@bind:event`.

#### ASP.NET Core 3.0

Quoting [ASP.NET Core 3.0 Component Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0) (currently unavailable) docs:

> Data binding to both components and DOM elements is accomplished with the `@bind` attribute. (...) Using `@bind` with a `CurrentValue` property (`<input @bind="CurrentValue" />`) is essentially equivalent to the following:

```
<input value="@CurrentValue"
       @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => CurrentValue = __e.Value)" />
```

> In addition to handling onchange events with `@bind` syntax, a property or field can be bound using other events by specifying an `@bind-value` attribute with an event parameter (`@bind-value:event`). *( `onchange`, `oninput` )*

**Summarizing**

If you want to reset binded value on each input change (instead to set all changes at once on lost input focus) you should to use `@bind-value` and `oninput` on `@bind-value:event`:

```
<input @bind-value="CurrentValue" 
       @bind-value:event="oninput" />
```

If you try to use `@bind-value:event` without `@bind-value` (using just `@bind` ) a pre-compiling error is raised:

> error RZ10004: Could not find the non-parameterized bind attribute that corresponds to the attribute 'bind-value:event'

But the `XXX.razor.g.cs` generated file is the same for `@bind` and `@bind-value`.

Comment: So this means it's the same, but if you want to add extra functionality (`:event`), you need to use `@bind-value` ?

Comment: @Vencovsky , this is that I understand from docs and what the tests confirm.

Comment: Do you also have the felling that the docs don't explain that much? Somethings are kind of blurry

Comment: I agree with this

Comment: Looks like we can do **@bind="CurrentValue"  @bind:event="oninput"** too!
Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRN30_Q2h_Y
This again asking me what really is the difference between **@bind** and **@bind-value**

Comment: @DragonWarrior In the current Version of the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) `@bind` and `@bind:event` are mentioned. `@bind-value` is not even used there. I also wonder why, but I strongly assume they are aliases and are exactly the same. (maybe the more verbose version is older???)

Comment: Thanks @somedotnetguy by your comment. Appreciate. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is not any significant deference between these two. The you can use @bind-value and @bind-value:event or you can use @bind and @bind:event pairs arbitrary.

Comment: Seems like the only restriction is, that it is not valid to mix them on the same element.