# difference between @bind-value and @bind in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

What is the difference between:

```
<input @bind-value="@field1" />
```

and

```
<input @bind="@field1" />
```

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between @bind and @bind-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221915/difference-between-bind-and-bind-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this simple sample - none, really. The second is a shortcut.

The @bind-... Indicates what parameter will be bound. More complex components don't usually map html attributes directly so you have to set the parameter name. Also, there may be more than one.

For example, the InputText component that you'd use in a form needs @bind-Value